# update iOS app with images from web

Tags: ios, image, web, uiimageview

I am working on free app and have 2 images (one transparent overlay) as background.I will have these two images changed from my web monthly. The update of images process, but how the app knows, if the image has changed on web? When launching the app I want to achieve the following:

1. check for updates available for pictures before launching app
2. download picture, store locally, use as background
3. if no new image available, use default
4. launch app

Can someone point to the right direction with the comparison/web request process please?

Here's what I have so far:

viewDidLoad method

```
 self.imageData = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.blahblah.com/newImage.jpg"]]delegate:self];
```

rest of code:

```
  - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
 {
    self.length = [response expectedContentLength];
 }
 - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [self.imageData appendData:data];
    float progress =  (float)[imageData length]/(float)self.length;
    [self.progressView setProgress:progress animated:YES];
}
 - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"didFailWithError");
}
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:self.imageData];
    self.backgroundImageView.image = img;
    [self saveLocally:self.imageData];
}
// save
- (void)saveLocally:(NSData *)imgData
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSDate *aDate = [NSDate date];
    NSTimeInterval interval = [aDate timeIntervalSince1970];
    NSString *localFilePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.jpeg",(int)interval]];
    [imgData writeToFile:localFilePath atomically:YES];
}
```

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few methods you could try out here, if I understand your problem correctly.

One way would be to post some text file on the web that contains the filenames and/or sizes of the image files which, if the file sizes don't match the images and their sizes that you have saved locally, you can then update (that is, download a new copy of) the images on your device.

This way, you would only download a very tiny file (the text file containing these numbers) before downloading the somewhat bigger image files.

Comment: Thanks Michael, I did upload .txt file and downloading images only when content changed

Answer (score 1):

i will prefer to have some json type feature in your app and check by imagename key value and compare the old image name string with the retrieve json data key value if u find changes, made changes i'm recently working on the similar type of app not exactly the same but yes server side app and have to provide the offline mode of app so what ever i get by json i usually save to my library even though the images as well and the next time when i do retrieve my json data i only sync which are new either category, image or what soever . its live streaming video app kind off bbc new app type